# eclipselink.logging.file is not working for me

Tags: logging, eclipselink

I am using Eclipselink 2.3.0 in a new project that is deployed in Glassfish 3.1.2 in an EAR file.

These are all the properties defined in my persistence.xml:

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="DefaultLogger"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.file" value="\logs\eclipselink.log"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="true"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="true"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="true"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true"/>
```

All of the properties work as expected, except for eclipselink.logging.file. It creates the file "\logs\eclipselink.log", but it is always empty, and the logging output goes to stdout.

I have tried changing from DefaultLogger to JavaLogger, and the file name to have the other direction slashes, etc, etc. Everything I try results in an empty log file, and the logging output going to stdout.

Any ideas as to why this is happening? It seems to me like EclipseLink is reading the properties correctly, and creating the file, but somewhere the output is being redirected to stdout.

P.S. There is only one persistence.xml in the EAR project, and this is the only project deployed in the Glassfish instance.

Comment: So, what is the result? Did you solved this problem? I faced it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the code that processes the properties, it seems it may be a bug.  Are you using a managed or application managed persistence unit?

My guess, is if you create your own subclass of DefaultSessionLog the file property will be applied.
You could also try setting the log file in a SessionCustomizer.

Please log a bug.

Comment: it is a container managed persistence unit. I know you can create your own log classes, but I wanted to avoid that kind of customisation. I might take your advice and log a bug, because it seems that setting the log file property should result in a log file being used.

Comment: So, what is the result? Did you solved this problem? I faced it too

Comment: I couldn't find a bug for this, was one filed?

Answer (score 0):

Take the following with a grain of salt, I peeked and the source but did not take the time to fully "grok" it.  I ran into the same issue and here is what I found (this was with unit tests without GlassFish running, so it was Java SE in this case).

It seems like DefaultLogger just seems to log to stdout.  I think the code can only handle one writer, and maybe stdout is always the last writer set?

With JavaLogger I too found at first that it creates the eclipselink.logging.file file, but does not log anything into it.  I think it is because a stream to the file is created and given to JavaLogger, but it ignores it.  I think it literally does just sort of pass everything to the java.util.logging system.  So what I needed to do was use java.util.logging properties to control the output file name (via java.util.logging.FileHandler) and the amount of logging:

Here is a subset of my logging properties (to be passed into the JVM or loaded manually with LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration):

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINEST
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = mylogfile%u.%g.log
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
org.eclipse.persistence.default.level = FINE
org.eclipse.persistence.session.level = FINE
```

Also in my persistence.xml file I no longer set a eclipselink.logging.file.

Answer (score 0):

> This property applies when used in a Java SE environment.

Source: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_logging_file.htm

For Java EE applications there is "ServerLogger".

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging#Server_Logging